# Xamarin iOS: Hard coding a specific location in CLGeocoder Api

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to pass a specific address in my geolocation. But

CLGeocoder.GeocodeAddressAsync("46 Grosvenor Pl, London SW1X 7EQ, United Kingdom");

But I am getting Geocoding Error. Can anyone kindly confirm if the address format is right? I even tried with out postcode, but failing for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var geoCoder = new CoreLocation.CLGeocoder();
    var placemarks = await geoCoder.GeocodeAddressAsync("46 Grosvenor Pl, London SW1X 7EQ, United Kingdom");
    foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(placemark);
    }
});
```

#### Results:

```
46 Grosvenor Place<GEOMapItemStorage: 0x79bdf890> {
    placeData =     {
        component =         (
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ENTITY";
                value =                 (
                                        {
                        entity =                         {
                            "is_disputed" = 0;
                            name =                             (
                                                                {
                                    locale = "en-US";
                                    "string_value" = "46 Grosvenor Place";
                                }
                            );
                            type = ADDRESS;
                        };
                    }
                );
                "values_available" = 1;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_PLACE_INFO";
                value =                 (
                                        {
                        "place_info" =                         {
                            center =                             {
                                lat = "51.498251";
                                lng = "-0.1474483";
                            };
                            timezone =                             {
                                identifier = "Europe/London";
                            };
                        };
                    }
                );
                "values_available" = 1;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ROAD_ACCESS_INFO";
                value =                 (
                                        {
                        "access_info" =                         {
                            "road_access_point" =                             (
                                                                {
                                    drivingDirection = "ENTRY_EXIT";
                                    isApproximate = 1;
                                    location =                                     {
                                        lat = "51.4981067";
                                        lng = "-0.1472507";
                                    };
                                    walkingDirection = "ENTRY_EXIT";
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    }
                );
                "values_available" = 1;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_BOUNDS";
                value =                 (
                                        {
                        bounds =                         {
                            "map_region" =                             {
                                eastLng = "-0.1469381274878062";
                                northLat = "51.49856860315036";
                                southLat = "51.49793339463645";
                                westLng = "-0.1479584796223861";
                            };
                        };
                    }
                );
                "values_available" = 1;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ADDRESS";
                value =                 (
                                        {
                        address =                         {
                            "known_accuracy" = POINT;
                            "localized_address" =                             (
                                                                {
                                    address =                                     {
                                        formattedAddressLine =                                         (
                                            "46 Grosvenor Place",
                                            London,
                                            "SW1X 7EQ",
                                            England
                                        );
                                        structuredAddress =                                         {
                                            administrativeArea = England;
                                            areaOfInterest =                                             (
                                                "Great Britain"
                                            );
                                            country = "United Kingdom";
                                            countryCode = GB;
                                            dependentLocality =                                             (
                                                Belgravia
                                            );
                                            fullThoroughfare = "46 Grosvenor Place";
                                            geoId =                                             (
                                            );
                                            locality = London;
                                            postCode = "SW1X 7EQ";
                                            subAdministrativeArea = London;
                                            subLocality = Belgravia;
                                            subThoroughfare = 46;
                                            thoroughfare = "Grosvenor Place";
                                        };
                                    };
                                    language = "en-US";
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    }
                );
                "values_available" = 1;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_RATING";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_HOURS";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                status = "STATUS_FAILED";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TRANSIT_INFO";
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                status = "STATUS_FAILED";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TRANSIT_SCHEDULE";
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_FLYOVER";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_AMENITIES";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_STYLE_ATTRIBUTES";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TRANSIT_INCIDENT";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TEXT_BLOCK";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_FACTOID";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TRANSIT_ATTRIBUTION";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            },
                        {
                "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
                "start_index" = 0;
                status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                timestampFirstSeen = "485089873.024917";
                ttl = 2592000;
                type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_RESULT_SNIPPET";
                "values_available" = 0;
                version = 1;
                "version_domain" =                 (
                    apple,
                    fwdgeo,
                    GB
                );
            }
        );
        referenceFrame = WGS84;
        "result_provider_id" = 0;
    };
}
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
```